# SharePoint hosted remote event receiver on check in

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-addin, check-in, remote-event-receiver

Just wanting a quick answer here. I am writing an SharePoint add-in on a 2013 environment that activates on a check in of an item in a library and it has to be cloud ready. Hence using a remote even receiver. Now I am unsure whether to use SharePoint hosted or provider hosted. The question here is, is it possible on a SharePoint hosted app or is the only way to used provider hosted?

Comment: Remote event receivers only supported in provider hosted apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote Event receivers are hosted as a web service remotely which is possible through only Provider hosted apps in SharePoint 2013

SharePoint hosted apps doesn't allow any objects to be hosted remotely so you should go with Provider Hosted Apps.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx